# I am unable to find robots.txt file in server but it is showing in url

Tags: wordpress, robots.txt

I am totally new. This may sound silly for you guys but i am stuck with it. On the site i am getting a robots.txt file. But when i look into the server there is no robots.txt file.

But it can be access with the url: [goodearthtermiteandpest.com/robots.txt](http://goodearthtermiteandpest.com/robots.txt)

Please do help me why this is happening and where is this file actually.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

The robots.txt file is being automatically generated by Wordpress, depending on your 'Allow search engines' setting:

https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-enable-site-for-search-engine

There are also plugins to edit the file if you need to:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-robots-txt/

More info:

https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-edit-my-robotstxt-file

Answer (score 0):

May be this file is generated by some seo plugin.
if not then this is hidden file in your wordpress root.

tickmark then "show hidden files" when you open your file manager:
check screen shot

http://prntscr.com/6wcxes